# Dialogflow trigger intent by name / path not by input

Tags: python, google-api, dialogflow-es

I am trying to trigger intents in dialogflow without user input. 
I am using python and the dialogflow API v2.

I know that I can use events with

```
session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()
event_input = dialogflow.types.EventInput()
query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(event=event_input)
session_client.detect_intent(query_input=query_input)
```

but it would be very tedious to name all intents with an event.

Why can I not just trigger an intent by its name or id / path?

I am thankful for any tip.

All the best,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no - there isn't a way to trigger an Intent by name.

I can't speculate about the reasoning behind this, but I can think of a couple of possibilities. Being able to trigger it by name avoids all the other logic processing that goes into determining if an Intent *should* be triggered. For example, if all the Input Contexts are met or if certain phrases match.

Dialogflow is designed to match input criteria against the Intent that best matches those criteria. Most of those criteria are meant to be text or spoken inputs, although Events are available for some exceptional things. It isn't clear why making Intents with Events set for them would be significantly more tedious than making the Intents in the first place.